# Python exception handler to recommend package

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, modules, dynamic-loading

Consider this python 3 snippet, where when an import exception is raised, a string 'e' is created that says: "No module named ' packageName'".

The goal is to simply say on exit, that the import error can perhaps be solved by installing a package of the same name. I came up with this, and it works but I'd like to make it better, if anyone has some tips.

```
except ImportError as e:
     e = e.replace("No module named '", "")
     e = e.replace("'", "")
     sys.exit("'Error: Try sudo pip install %s'" % e)
```

Example output:

> Error: Try sudo pip install Crypto

Comment: As a side-note, here is a project of mine that I haven't worked on for a long time and designed to add suggestion to error messages : https://github.com/SylvainDe/DidYouMean-Python . Many things are still to be done (pip installable, more suggestions, usable with -m option, etc) but you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An `ImportError` instance doesn't have a `replace` method.

You can use `e.name` instead of messy string replacements.

---

Instead of `'%s' % x`, it's recommended to use `'{}'.format(x)`.

---

The example output is not what you posted, but actually this:

> 'Error: Try sudo pip install Crypto'

That is, it's surrounded by single quotes, because you wrote as `"'some text'"`.
Probably you want to remove those single quotes inside the string.

---

What does the message even mean?

This would make a lot more sense:

> Error: could not import 'Crypto'. Try installing with: pip install --user Crypto

---

Last, but most importantly, please don't recommend to install Python packages system-wide. This is a more sensible recommendation:

```
pip install --user the_package
```

This doesn't need `sudo`, as it will install the package in the user's home directory, not system-wide.

---

Putting it together:

```
try:
    import somename
except ImportError as e:
    sys.exit("Error: could not import '{0}'. Try installing with: pip install --user {0}".format(e.name))
```

Comment: linux thing to do sudo

Comment: @j0h no, doing `sudo` is not a "linux thing" at all. `sudo` is not to be taken lightly. It's not meant to run commands willy-nilly.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, this code doesn't work.  `e` is an `ImportError` instance, not a string, and so it doesn't have a `replace` method; you want to operate on `e.msg` instead.

Secondly, the messages generated this way will be *wrong* a non-negligible number of times, as modules aren't always available in PyPI packages of the same name.  The `bs4` module is in the beautifulsoup4 package, `yaml` is in PyYAML, `png` is in PurePNG, etc.  If you want these error messages to actually be useful, you'll have to explicitly code a different `try ... except` for every foreign `import`.

Moving on to more stylistic issues, there is technically no guarantee that an `ImportError`'s message will always be of the form `"No module named '%s'"`, and even if it were guaranteed, using a regex would probably be a better way to extract the name of the unimportable module.  However, since Python 3.3, you don't need to mess around with the error message, as the name of the module is available as the `e.name` attribute of the `ImportError`.